# Remove elements from array attributes of a Backbone model

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

My model is

```
var Storage = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        q_category_id : 2,
        dimension: []
    }
});
```

I have a model instance named `storageInfo` filled with

```
{
    "q_category_id":2,
    "dimension":[
        {"q_id":1,"q_text":"...","data_type":"1","meta":"15","answer":"152"},
        {"q_id":2,"q_text":"...","data_type":"1","meta":"30","answer":"302"},
        {"q_id":3,"q_text":"...","data_type":"1","meta":"60","answer":"602"}
    ]
}
```

but before sending to the server I want the model to be like this:

```
{
    "q_category_id":2,
    "dimension":[
        {"q_id":1,"answer":"152"},
        {"q_id":2,"answer":"302"},
        {"q_id":3,"answer":"602"}
    ]
}
```

How can I remove attributes like `q_text`, `datatype` and `meta` from the `dimension` array of my model?

Comment: Careful with mutable objects in `defaults`, the references are copied into new models as needed rather than cloned so your `dimension` array is subject to surprising reference sharing. `defaults: function() { return { ... } }` is a better approach in such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the underscore [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and [pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) methods to do this quite succinctly:

```
storageInfo.dimensions = _.map(storageInfo.dimensions, function(obj) {
    return _.pick(obj, 'p_id', 'answer');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate through the dimensions before saving the model, using pick as suggested by net.uk.sweet.
Otherwise, try to change the toJSON method of this model so it always returns the fields you would prefer:

```
var Storage = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
     q_category_id : 2,
     dimension: []
   },
   toJSON: function () {
     var dims = _.pick(this.get('dimensions'), ['q_id', 'answer']);
     return {q_category_id: this.get('q_category_id'), dimensions: dims}
   }
});
```